# Room for computational geometry in advanced algorithms course

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

I am currently putting together an independent study in advanced algorithms and because of my interest in (computational) geometry, wanted to include as many interesting algorithms from this field as possible.  Does anyone have any suggestions for material that might be suitable?

You may assume the math background acquired from an undergraduate CS degree, along with a high motivation to learn more if necessary (i.e. to learn about interesting problems).

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point would be Joseph O'Rourke's site [here](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/).

Answer (score 0):

Given a bunch of ink blobs on a plane. Find the shortest path between any two given points out of the ink and not touching the ink.